# (ImageSource) command in wpf copy image file to another folder and runs it from there

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i put images in (images) folder and use it like this:

```
<Ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Add Users" ImageSource="/images/add-user.png"/>
```

but i find a copy of them in other folder (called window) that it using it for saving wpf pages.

when i try to do it using properties , miscellaneous, command is being added like this: (i choose (images) folder )

```
<Ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Add Users" ImageSource="/window/add-user.png"/>
```

and again there is copy of (add-user.png) in window folder

Comment: are you building an exe or a dll assembly?  I found that when building WPF controls dll's you have to pack the images into a resource and reference the resource for them to travel with the assembly.

Comment: building an exe program